# Django: Некорректное отображение шаблонов на локальном сервере

Tags: django

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с необычной проблемой. На локальном сервере (./manage.py runserver) некоторые части шаблона отображаются неверно, хотя все статические файлы (css, js) загружены и, в целом, страница корректна. В то же время на production-сервере, где статика загружается через nginx, всё в норме.

[image: Локально]
[image: Production]

Comment: и все же, я думаю, стоит приложить к вопросу всю инфу (ctrl+f 'static') из файлов project.settings и project.urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это потому что сервер django на локальной машине не заботится о раздачи статики.

В Django есть решение из коробки, которое заботится о раздаче статики.

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll **also need to actually
>   serve the static files.**
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
>   [django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve)).
>
> This method is **grossly inefficient** and probably **insecure**, so it is
>   unsuitable for production.

Примерное решение

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    ]
```

Подробнее:

- [Static file development view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view)

**Ещё раз:**
Не используйте без `DEBUG = True`. Это решение может быть небезопасным и ресурсоёмким